# Cant download PDF with Ajax response (headers are ignored)

Tags: ajax, symfony, superagent

Im trying to download a pdf with ajax request yet the response from that request ignores my "Content-Type:application/pdf" header.

**The ajax request**

```
return Superagent.post(url, data).use(this._addDefaults.bind(this));
```

**The symfony response**

```
return new BinaryFileResponse($target);
```

**Workaround**

open in new tab and put a direct url for the file.

Comment: How are you requesting it? GET or POST? can we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is similar to a problem I've encountered in the past. Issue is that browsers don't open responses to POST ajax requests by default. I ended up resorting to the automatic form posting instead. In the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="http://handler1.ashx" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="post_body_stuff"/>
  <button id="pdfsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">Export to PDF</button>
</form>
```

You can use javascript to put all the data you want to POST as the value on the hidden input field instead of `post_body_stuff`. This way, when the content comes back the browser will try to open or save it as a file rather than read it as response text.